# Make Wordpress Elementor Testimonial Carousel Height scale with content

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have Elementor Testimonial Carousel, but the height doesn't scale with content leaving a lot of whitespace.

This is what I came up with, but it only works for the buttons. When I swipe, the height will still be bugged.

```
testimonialsAutoHeight('.elementor-swiper-button-next');
testimonialsAutoHeight('.elementor-swiper-button-prev');
  
function testimonialsAutoHeight(btn) {
      jQuery('body').on('click', btn, function() {
          
          var testimonial_height = jQuery('.swiper-slide-active .elementor-testimonial').height();
          testimonial_height = testimonial_height + 80;
          
          jQuery('[isMobileCarousel] .elementor-widget-container').css('height', testimonial_height);
      });
}
```

Comment: looks like your carousel uses swiper js... it  has this capability already built it in: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-autoHeight

Comment: @mikerojas How do I apply this to an already existing carousel?

Comment: Do you access to the carousel settings?

Comment: @mikerojas there's no such setting on the Elementor editor